# Add matrices with different labels and different dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have two large square matrices ( in two CSV files). The two matrices may have a few different labels and different dimensions. 
I want to add these two matrices and retain all labels. How do I do this in python?

Example:

{a, b, c ... e} are labels.

```
        a   b   c   d               a   e
    a   1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5         a   9.1 9.2
X=  b   2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4     Y=  e   8.1 8.2
    c   3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6                 
    d   4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5                 

            a       b       c       d       e
        a   1.2+9.1 1.3     1.4     1.5     9.2
X+Y=    b   2.1     2.2     2.3     2.4     0
        c   3.3     3.4     3.5     3.6     0
        d   4.2     4.3     4.4     4.5     0
        e   8.1     0       0       0       8.2
```

If someone wants to see the files (matrices), they are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhTExOUFZqQkQ1VTQ?usp=sharing).

** Trying the method suggested by @piRSquared

```
import pandas as pd
X= pd.read_csv('30203_Transpose.csv')
Y= pd.read_csv('62599_1999psCSV.csv')

Z= X.add(Y, fill_value=0).fillna(0)

print Z
```

Z -> 467 rows x 661 columns

The resulting matrix should be square too. 
This approach also causes the row headers to be lost ( now become 1,2,3 .. , They should be 10010, 10071, 10107, 1013 ..)

```
    10010   10071   10107   1013 ....
0   0   0   0.01705 0.0439666659
1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0.0382000022
3   0.0663666651    0   0   0.0491333343
4   0   0   0   0
5   0.0208000001    0   0   0.1275333315
.
.
```

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1):

use the `add` method with the parameter `fill_value=0`

```
X.add(Y, fill_value=0).fillna(0)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this. The row labels are altered in the process and resulting matrix is rectangular ( should be square)
Is there a way around?