# Add two matrices having different dimensions, labels and retain labels in sum matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have two square matrices as two csv files. Each matrix has a row and column label. Each row, column label detects relation score between two companies. 
Both the marices have a few labels (companies) which are missing in the other. Also, the dimensions of both matrices are different. ( One is 427 x 427, other is 467 x 467 )

Ex: In the matrix below, the numbers in bold are labels (company serial numbers).

```
0 is the score between (10010, 10010) . 
0.43967 is the score between (1013, 10010) and so on.
```

[image]

I need to add these two matrices in such a way that:
In the resulting matrix ( sum of the two matrix), no label (row or column labels) is lost. **If label exist in A and not in B, the resulting matrix should have a row & column entry (label and values) for it and vice versa for B.**

```
Example: 
Note that {a, b ... e} are labels. X & Y are matrices. 
       a   b   c   d               a   e
    a   1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5         a   9.1 9.2
X=  b   2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4     Y=  e   8.1 8.2
    c   3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6                 
    d   4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5                 

            a       b       c       d       e
        a   1.2+9.1 1.3     1.4     1.5     9.2
X+Y=    b   2.1     2.2     2.3     2.4     0
        c   3.3     3.4     3.5     3.6     0
        d   4.2     4.3     4.4     4.5     0
        e   8.1     0       0       0       8.2
```

I had posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749442/add-matrices-with-different-labels-and-different-dimensions) but the answer given did not take into account the row labels and made the resulting matrix rectangular. **The resulting matrix must be square too**.

I am lost at how this should be done in python/ pandas or any other python libraries. Can someone help me with this?

The matrix files are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhTExOUFZqQkQ1VTQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the columns and indices labels are the same values, if you take the union of the columns and reindex both dfs and fill the `NaN` with `0` prior to adding then you get the result you desire.

if the column and index labels are not the same you can just make 2 arrays of the combined labels:

```
all_cols = x.columns | y.columns
all_indices = x.index | y.index
```

and `reindex`.

With your example data:

```
In [11]:
all_cols = x.columns | y.columns
x = x.reindex(index=all_cols, columns=all_cols).fillna(0)
y = y.reindex(index=all_cols, columns=all_cols).fillna(0)
x+y

Out[11]:
      a    b    c    d    e
a  10.3  1.3  1.4  1.5  9.2
b   2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  0.0
c   3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  0.0
d   4.2  4.3  4.4  4.5  0.0
e   8.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  8.2
```

Actually you can just `reindex` the result of `add`:

```
In [13]:
x.add(y, fill_value=0).reindex(index=all_cols,columns=all_cols).fillna(0)

Out[13]:
      a    b    c    d    e
a  10.3  1.3  1.4  1.5  9.2
b   2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  0.0
c   3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  0.0
d   4.2  4.3  4.4  4.5  0.0
e   8.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  8.2
```

**EDIT**

regarding your real data, you need to specify that the first unnamed column is the index:

```
X= pd.read_csv('30203_Transpose.csv', index_col=0)
Y= pd.read_csv('62599_1999psCSV.csv', index_col=0)
```

Additionally your index is not the same as your columns so these need to be aggregated separately

```
all_cols = X.columns | Y.columns
all_indices = X.index | Y.index
```

then you can `add`:

```
X.add(Y, fill_value=0).reindex(index=all_cols,columns=all_cols).fillna(0)
```

Comment: The sum results in 0's everywhere. See [Matrix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ahydyrHjTZIih67KALIOhDFlnZRAZ0c9pFPqvFUU8g/edit) .

I have the files and the python code [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhTExOUFZqQkQ1VTQ) . Please take a look if possible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with `all_cols = x.columns | y.columns
all_indices = x.index | y.index` and pass `all_indices` as the `index` param for `reindex`, this worked for me

Comment: The matrix becomes rectangular and the row labels go missing. See [Matrix](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nZn4-Xhu9NMAUCFx7196anSY_7nWmdHlcHv-F_JDDok) . The modified code is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0byAC8kZZPhN1BlTW11U0N0bUk)

Comment: You also need to add `index_col=0` to `read_csv`: `X= pd.read_csv('30203_Transpose.csv', index_col=0)
Y= pd.read_csv('62599_1999psCSV.csv', index_col=0)`

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!